# Manipulate only the element which the mouse hovers over jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function in my script which is meant to manipulate the navigation of a html page. My problem is I have multiple `<nav>...</nav>` blocks of code and when I use the code below it affects all of them.

```
$(function () {
    $('nav').hover(function () {
        $('nav').animate({ top: '-=100px' }, 1000, 'easeOutBounce', null);
    });
});
```

Therefore I assumed the logical thing to do would be specify which nav block was generating the hover event, however when using `this` inside the function fired when a hover event was in place nothing happened.

```
$(function () {
    $('nav').hover(function () {
        this.animate({ top: '-=100px' }, 1000, 'easeOutBounce', null);
    });
});
```

How am I able to identify and manipulate the nav block which is being hovered over on its own and not affect all the nav blocks at once.

**Edit**

For example if I were to have these three `nav` blocks and I want them to only be manipulated by the function if the `nav` block is being hovered over, how would I differentiate between them.

```
<nav id="nav1"></nav>
<nav id="nav2"></nav>
<nav id="nav3"></nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this)` instead of `this`

```
$(function () {
    $('nav').hover(function () {
        $(this).animate({top: '-=100px' }, 1000, 'easeOutBounce', null);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will accept when in 8 mins when it lets me

Comment: @Dan glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to even use JQuery for it. Also that's not the way to use nav.

Nav is a semantic HTML5 tag. There's nothing wrong using it like that right now, but in the future, browser will start using this tags properly, and that could cause some issues. Think of a nav, as you are telling the browser "Hey, here is my navigation"

Use nav like this and write this simple CSS code, and it will work.

HTML

```
<nav>
<ul>
   <li>Element 1</li>
   <li>Element 2</li>
   <li>Element 3</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
li{ /* Write your non active element styling here */}

li:hover{ /* Write your hovered element styling here */}
```

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I was trying to use an easing function which as far as I am aware you can use in CSS

Comment: @Dan, actually you can do animation and easing in CSS using "transition"

Comment: I know but the specific transition I was using is not available in css [look here](http://easings.net/#easeInOutBounce)

Answer (score -1):

$('nav') will give you a collection of all nav elements on the page. Put an id attribute on the one you want to target and use that.

```
<nav id="targetNav"></nav>

$('#targetNav').hover(...)
```